# Converting bean from spring to spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

My problem statement is as follows :
I want to connect to db and from a table get certain values and assign those to a bean. In current spring project, it is done as follows :

The class com.some.DbPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is in a jar file.

```
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
                class="com.some.DbPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
                <property name="dataSourceName" value="dataSource" />
                <property name="locations">
                    <list>
                        <value>classpath:resources/context.properties</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>

<bean id="someObject" class="com.some.beans.SomeObject">
        <property name="someprop" value="${prefix.someprop}" />
        <property name="someprop1" value="${prefix.someprop1}" />
        <property name="someprop2" value="${prefix.someprop2}" />
        ....
    </bean>
```

DbPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is in a jar file, it reads from a db table.
The Db table has key value columns.
The key contains "prefix.someprop" and it has some value.

Now, I am working on converting spring beans into spring boot beans using annotations.
Following is the bean in spring.
I came up with following for spring boot but bean it is not getting initialized.
I am not sure how to map properties "dataSourceName" and "locations"

```
    @Configuration
    public class AppConfig {

        @Bean
        public DbPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
            return new DbPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }

        @Bean
        public SomeObject someObject() {
           return new SomeObject();
        }
    }
```

It throws following exception :

```
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.some.configuration.DbPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(DbPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:130)
```

Also if it gets initialzed, how will I actually use it ?

Comment: To load a property in Spring Boot use @PropertySource annotation.

Comment: So should I autowire DbPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Comment: Yeah if you are using it anywhere you use the bean anywhere you need to autowire it.

Comment: Modified my question to get some more clarity. Where can I set name="dataSourceName" value="dataSource" in Spring boot like I am doing in spring?